# Type Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Tags: java, android

I am getting an error in 2 places and I don't know why as I am new to Android...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
    Context context=getApplication();
    CharSequence text = "This is for ontouch event";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast Msg = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
     int x=(int)event.getX();
     int y=(int)event.getY();
     Msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
     Msg.show();

     return true;
 } //Error type Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    

TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
t1.isClickable();

t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
}  // Error Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

Comment: which places? what errors?

Comment: move `TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)` and the `setOnLongClickListener` inside onCreate

Comment: do you use IDE for development ?

Comment: I am using only eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

class file...

```
package com.longclick;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
       t1.isClickable();

      t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           return true;
        }
     });

}

//@Override
//public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    //return true;
//}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    Context context=getApplication();
    CharSequence text = "This is for ontouch event";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast Msg = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
     int x=(int)event.getX();
     int y=(int)event.getY();
     Msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
     Msg.show();

    return true;
} //Error type Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    


}
```

.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think it is working for you...

[image]

demo [here](https://doc-04-3o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/f8eqvk2a7nsjgghojnld3mt6t1686h3n/147j6h2co8dcjdn43f58fdgh8andn4ej/1372312800000/01527135014055334986/01527135014055334986/0B-M16hFRreCbNF9nd0ZQOW10RHc?e=download&h=16653014193614665626&nonce=7jimi3cv3bteu&user=01527135014055334986&hash=vtuvpqgscbnmpkbvkpqiaalsd303vfvo)

Comment: Thanks for ur code it was really helpful & I found my mistake. Actually it was not working at that time bcoz my text view size was too small. So now I have increased my textview size & now it is woking fine.. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should explain the reason of the problem instead of spoon feeding.

Comment: @waqar I'm not teacher to give lectures or explanations of the questions. I just give solution for problems and here it is.

Answer (score 2):

Write your TextView code in `onCreate()` method, you can't write this code outside any function the way you have written.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    t1.isClickable();

    t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Edit and post your whole code here.

Answer (score 1):

Move this inside `onCreate`

```
  TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
  t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: now it is not giving any error but onLongClick method is not working is something wrong in that???

Comment: did you use activity context? post your updated code by editing the question

Comment: try using `MainActivity.this`. `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,"Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the entire code and try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
   t1.isClickable();
   t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Text View Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {
    Context context=getApplication();
    CharSequence text = "This is for ontouch event";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast Msg = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
     int x=(int)event.getX();
     int y=(int)event.getY();
     Msg.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
     Msg.show();

     return true;
  //Error type Syntax error on token "}", delete this token    


}  // 
}
```

This should definitely work and click the text for a long time .Sure it will give you the output.

Comment: Before executing the updated code uninstall the app from your device or from you emulator and start updating.

Comment: delete the gen folder in your project explorer and run the application again

Comment: i have deleted whole application and made a new 1 and tried to run it but still same thing it is nt giving output for long click

Comment: In the execution of a long click method type this code Log.d("Check","You have clicked the textview");. After execution of the application go to Log cat and see for "Check" Tag and ensure whether it is printing the msg or not.Then only it is entering to the method block correctly or caught with some error.

Comment: R u sure? I think you are not clicking for a longtime.It should be different from a normal click.Sorry to say this my guess may be wrong.

Comment: no i am clicking for a long time only for 1 min i pressed it but still it is not working

Comment: If you clicked long time it will show the msg in Logcat definitely.Then only it will enter your onLongClick method.Or else it will not even enter into that code

Comment: I think it is not entering in my code so what should i do now?

Comment: Try the same code again.Once it is worked means it will never fail again

Answer (score 0):

This code is outside of any function:

```
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    t1.isClickable();

    t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Check your functions structure.

Comment: now it is not giving any error but onLongClick method is not working is something wrong in that???

Comment: Try Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Check that your TextView have param in xml: android:longClickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

The last two paragraphs of your code need a function to wrap them, possibly `onCreate`.
You need to call `setLongClickable` on the view for the long click to register.

Comment: now it is not giving any error but onLongClick method is not working is something wrong in that???

Comment: @user2526627 you moved it into `onCreate`?

Comment: @user2526627 you might need to call [setLongClickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLongClickable%28boolean%29)

Comment: @user2526627 and `t1.isClickable();` is a check, it doesnt make it clickable.

Comment: @user2526627 try my other comments

Comment: @user2526627 `t1.setLongClickable(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t1.isClickable();
t1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Text View Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
});
```

}

Click the text for a long time and don't leave it quickly.

It is working fine.

Comment: onclick was working earlier also but onLongClick is not working with that

Comment: Or try this change getBaseContext to getApplicationContext() in Toast method

Comment: Clean the code and try it.Because it is working perfectly without any complications.Is it throwing error for you are not working for your onclick

Comment: or try this in your textview declaration                                                   TextView t1=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text);